Kubernetes deployment; all new pods first before deleting existing pods
Is it possible to configure the deployment.yaml for a rolling deployment in k8s to spin up all new pods before the "old" pods are deleted?
Background:
We have long living TCP connections distributed over 2 pods. When a pod is deleted and therefore the tcp connection closed, the tcp clients try to reconnect immediately.
So after a deployment all tcp connections are established on the pod which was updated first, instead of distributed evenly.

Kubernetes offers a rolling update strategy with zero downtime. So, to answer your question.
Yes, it is possible to configure your deployment yaml for a rolling update to spin up all pods before deleting the old pods. To make this work you need to set the maxSurge and maxUnavailable options in your deployment yaml. Set the maxSurge equals to the number of replicas and maxUnavailable to 0 as shown below.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 4 # Adjust the number of replicas as needed
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: n-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: n-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: nginx            
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080 # Adjust the port as needed
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 4 # Spin up all new pods before scaling down old pods
      maxUnavailable: 0 # To ensure no pods are unavailable during the update

Here maxSurge will help to create a new set of pods at a time and maxUnavailable will make sure the number of pods need to be deleted before new pods are up.
Note: make sure you have enough resources to create a new set of pods at the same time keeping all the existing pods.
